# default value is some value in wpf combobox which is not expected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have a WPF combobox and even though I set selected index as 0, nothing effective takes place. This is the combobox. What it displays by default is, 3rd (Last element in my list of tuple).

Like say I have A, B, C, it displays "C". I want to disable this combobox so that it appears read only and also display A.... The problem again is, it is binded to another textbox, where if I change the value of textbox, the corresponding value in dropdown gets displayed. I do not want this to happen...any thoughts?

I am thinking to make textbox readonly now...but what about default value display to "A"?

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="ckbilling" Grid.Column="2"
                              Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" 
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding BillToType}" 
                                          SelectedValuePath="Item1"                                  
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Item2"                                  
                                  />

 <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding BillToType}" IsReadOnly="True" ></TextBox>
```

Comment: some code will be required

Comment: If you don't want that to happen, then why do you have a binding from your combobox to your textbox? Didn't you mean to bind the textbox to your combobox?

Comment: @nit: the code i paste above, not getting displayed :(

Comment: @Silvermind: I am new to WPF, I really dont understand. I do some defect fix now on a new application I start working, and or improve the UI as per the client change requirements... please help...

Comment: @Silvermind: I want the combobox to display first value and it shouldn't be editable by user. i.e user shouldn't be able to click on dropdown or select any value. At the same time, I want the textbox also should be like readyonly, because when I change textbox value, apparently combo value changes.... the later part I know, I can make textbox readonly, but when I set selectedindex = 0, it still doesn't display 1st value but 3rd value

Comment: Please show the XAML of the textbox used too.

Comment: @BlueM: This is the xaml, but i just made it readonly...     <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                             Text="{Binding BillToType}" IsReadOnly="True"                           
                             ></TextBox>

Comment: What means default value for combobox for you. If textbox is empty?

Comment: @BlueM: Default value means value "A" but it shows "C"....I dont understand why the hell it shows "C" always and in other combobox, it shows "B" by default. WHy is this behavior?

Comment: It will always show the value you have bound to. Please list your existing Type tuples. (edit your question for it)

Answer (score 0):

WPF doesn't work this way. You don't set selected index to a certain position. Thats what binding is for. In your case your selected value is bound to the `BillType` property.

So if you want to change the selected value change `BillType` programmatically to one of your `Types` (in your example A).

Provided that the `BillType` property is correctly implemented by utilizing of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Inotify is implemented I think as it all has "RaisePropertyChanged" stuffs....Also, I am not sure about your 2nd point :(...The funny thing with WPF is, initially it showed nothing in drop down, but when I set selected index, it showed some value "C" and even when I make selected index to -1 now as it was earlier, it still shows "C" and not the blank default thing....strange

Comment: Do you set `BillType` like instructed? Do NOT set selected index. If you have elements in `Types` list you can try setting `BillType = Types.FirstOrDefault();`. You can do that after the Types property is filled with data.

Comment: Thank you, why I shouldn't use selected index? This is how we do in Winforms and many internet blog say to do this....anyway, is there anyway to simply this implementation? I mean, in xaml any possibility to set this?

Comment: Also, its strange that why it displays some value by default in the dropdown (In my case its 2rd value) and more funny thing with MS WPF is, another combobox displays 2nd value

Comment: It depends as to what value `BillType` is set. As said quite easy to change. No need for selectedIndex

Comment: Blue, remember, I have three properties

Comment: public IEnumerable<System.Tuple<string,string>> Types
        {
            get { return editionService.ListOfTypes; }
        }

Comment: public string BillToType
        {
            get { return shipment!=null ? shipment.TransportationPaymentType : null ; }
            set
            {
                shipment.TransportationPaymentType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("BillToType");
                RaisePropertyChanged("BillToAccount");
            }
        }

Comment: Can you not see Inotify implemented? Well my requirement is simple. I should make both textbox and combo readonly and the value displayed in combo should be first value, say "A"

Comment: Can you tell me the type of your `BillType` property?

Comment: Its String......sorry, my in XAML, it is SelectedValue="{Binding BillToType}"  its string as mentioned above property